# Separate hex blocks in PHP

Tags: php, hex

Anyone knows an way to "separate" the blocks of this hex code?

```
[49cd0d18] -> 1238175000
[00010000] -> 1
[0069] -> 105
[543ace68] -> timestamp
000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Complete:
49cd0d1800010000543ace68000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Oh, of course... This values, can be different... I just know, that will not be the same. So, I need to know how to "count" blocks, and then, "cut".

I'll be very grateful with your help!

Comment: Are the section always the same number of characters?

Otherwise, it will be pretty hard to extract something without some kind of delimiter.

Comment: Yes, only change the hex values. But characters lenght, is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex are easy solution for problem like theses:

You can see the regex on that link: https://regex101.com/r/qP1bC7/1

Note: Don't forget to put delimiter (the slashes in my example) around your regex when you use it in your code :

```
/^(\w{8})(\w{8})(\w{4})(\w{8})(\w{39})$/
```

1. The caret and the dollar sign delimit respectively the beginning and the ending of the string.
2. The parenthesis are capturing groups.
3. `\w` match any letter (A-Z in lower and upper case), the digits (0-9) and underscore (_).
4. `{8}` means that it must match exactly 8 characters

And you can see an example of the code here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3a0ec3a45c53eb2c1b8e21cb978253ea4a28e52

The third parameter is an array to store the match of the regex (it is passed by reference, so you have to create it before using it). The first (0) index will be the whole match and the successive index (1-6) will the result of the capturing groups (there are 5 of them).

You could also extract substring with PHP native functions.

```
$string = "49cd0d18000100000069543ace68000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

$matches = array();

$matches[] = substr($string, 0, 8);

$matches[] = substr($string, 8, 8);

$matches[] = substr($string, 16, 4);

$matches[] = substr($string, 20, 8);

$matches[] = substr($string, 28, 39);

var_dump($matches);
```

You can test the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18935d55feb86dffdc17f8854572e0935b4aab0e

**Additional note**: PHP native functions are faster than regex. The regular expressions have to be compile every time you use them (but PHP keep a pool of the last 1000 regexes used). You can benchmark both solutions if performance is an important matter. Otherwise, I'd say that both solutions are pretty equivalent.

Good success and don't forget to like,

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque from Montreal